# How to display following values using vue js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, vue-component

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "source": "n",
    "sortBy": "top",
    "articles": [
        {
            "author": "Bradford ",
            "title": "friends.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        },
        {
            "author": "Bradford  ",
            "title": "Kershaw threw six mesmerizing innings to put L.A. into the Fall Classic.",
            "url": "http: //",
            "urlToImage": "http://"
        }
    ]
}
```

My vue js script is

```
<script>
feed = new Vue({
    'el': '#feed',
    data: {
        articles: [],
    },
    mounted: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=espn&sortBy=top&apiKey=4db9d5d381a14ffcbca8e8a9aa8b864c",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {},
            success: function (e) {
                if (e.status == ok) {
                    self.data = e.data;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

And displaying as

```
        <div v-for="post in articles" class="mke_">
            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"><img src="//placehold.it/130" class="media-object"></div>
    {{post.title}}
        </div></div>
```

Can sombody please help me to display the content in articles[]? I am weak in vue js.. Is the pattern right.

Comment: Your code looks okay.  Is something not working?  Are you not seeing the titles?

Comment: It should be `self.articles = e.data;`

Comment: I have one more doubt.. How to display only 3rd and 5th row? Can you please help me

Comment: use `vue-resource` instead for `jquery`.

You would call `data` and it would show `undefined` so modified your data into variable what you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Your *vue script* should be like this

```
<script>
 new Vue({
  el: '#feed' ,
  data: {
    articles: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
            url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=espn&sortBy=top&apiKey=4db9d5d381a14ffcbca8e8a9aa8b864c",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (e) {
                if (e.status == 'ok') {
                    self.articles = e.articles;
                    console.log(e.articles)
                }
            }, error: function(){
            console.log('Error occurred');
            }
        });
    })
  },
})
</script>
```

Your html

```
 <div id="feed">
  <div v-for="post in articles" class="mke_">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"><img src="//placehold.it/130" class="media-object"></div>
          {{post.title}}
        </div>
 </div>
```

You can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/adkstar/hf9w9zL3/

EDITED:
To display only the third and fifth article only, you can do

```
  <div v-for="(post,index) in articles" class="mke_">
    <div v-if="(index == 3 || index == 5)">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"><img src="//placehold.it/130" class="media-object"></div>
            {{post.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir.

Comment: I have one more doubt.. How to display only 3rd and 5th row? Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you have saved the context in **self** variable.
You just need to edit your code with `self.articles = e.articles;`
Once the data has been bind to `self.articles`, Vue is going to invoke `articles` getter/setter functions (Declarative reactive rendering concept) and update it.
**Updated Answer:**
Edit your html with:

```
<div v-for="(post,index) in articles" class="mke_">
            <div class="row" v-if="index == 3 || index == 5">
          <div class="col-md-1"><img src="//placehold.it/130" class="media-object"></div>
    {{post.title}}
        </div></div>
```

Comment: I have one more doubt.. How to display only 3rd and 5th row? Can you please help me

Comment: Sure I am editing my answer check it out. Do upvote it.

Comment: flush data structure is more efficient than query every single index when your life cycle get into `checked`.